# How to get a selected value of dropdownlist from View to controller then pass it over again to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this DropdownList which reads an enum:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HoursScale,
new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CalendarComponets.Models.Data.ScaleLine.Scales))), "Select Scale")
```

I need to get the value of selected value of the dropdownlist in my controller and again pass it over to my view and show it like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(vm => vm.Scale)
```

I am new with asp.net mvc so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your selected item by using the model. You need to have this to get the returning value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourPageName(ModelName model)
{
     ViewBag.Item = model.HoursScale;
     return RedirectToAction("PageName", "ControllerName");
}
```

And on the page you want to display the value, coming from your input:

```
<p>@ViewBag.Item</p>
```

In this example I am thinking that you already made the model named, in my case,  ModelName with something like:

```
public string HoursScale { get; set; } // Maybe other returning value than string?
```

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }

    //other codes.....
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId , new SelectList(Model.YourBindField))
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(YourViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ///....
        var selectedIndex = viewModel.SelectedId ;
        ///....            
    }
```